# calling movieclip of a class from another class, error#1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i got error: method of null object reference. I'm so confused and don't know what is the real cause.
So i got a player movieClip on the stage which has an instance of "player_mc", which will be pass thru my Document class and into the Player class.
**Player.as**

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;


public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    public var myPlayer:MovieClip;

    public function Player(player:MovieClip)
    {
        myPlayer = player;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,on_enter);
    }
```

**Document.as**

```
import flash.display.*;
import Components.Player.Player;

public class Game_Main extends MovieClip
{

    public var player:Player;


    public function Game_Main()
    {
        player = new Player(player_mc);


    }

}
```

now here i think is where the problem comes from. I have a green_enemy movieclip on the stage which has base class Enemy.
**Enemy.as**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Components.Player.Player;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Enemy extends MovieClip
{
    var theplayer:Player;


    public function Enemy()
    {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,on_enter);
    }

    public function on_enter(e:Event):void
    {
        if (this.hitTestObject(theplayer.myPlayer)) //calls player_mc from Player class
        {
            trace("hi");
        }


    }



}
```

what I like to do on Enemy function is when Enemy collides with "player_mc" (which is on the stage) it will do something. Maybe my code is wrong.
Any help/tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Enemy.as I see

```
var theplayer:Player;
```

not initialized. It is private, so you can not define it from outside. That means that exception comes from here

```
this.hitTestObject(theplayer.myPlayer)
```

You are trying to call `myPlayer` from **null**.

Try to define this variable while constructing Enemy class.

---

To prevent null exception you can check if theplayer is null

```
public function on_enter(e:Event):void
{
    if (theplayer && this.hitTestObject(theplayer.myPlayer)) 
    {
        trace("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is stupid, but can you show me what'd you mean? Im just progressing on as3 lately so sorry for being dumb.

Comment: Nothing to apologise. Change `var theplayer:Player;` to `public var theplayer:Player;` like John Dodson said. And don't forget to define green_enemy.theplayer = yourPlayer. Also see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what ZuyEL said, your variable isn't globally defined in your enemy class since you're just adding a var inside your enemy function. Instead, do the following

```
public var thePlayer:Player;
```

write the above after your Enemy class, before the Enemy function. Now it is available to the whole class and will no longer be null when you call it later.